# Pandas Dataframe and Structured Data

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a way to express a 2D matrix of structs.

I have a list of sensors at different places. Each sensor monitor 4 attributes. Each sensor monitors things every 5 minutes. It seems natural to organize this as a dataframe that looks like the following. But I am not sure if it is indeed natural to use it if I do this.

```
            Sensor1                 Sensor2                  Sensor3
       long lat angle temp      long lat angle temp     long lat angle temp
10:00
10:05
10:10
10:15
10:20
10:25
...
```

In other words, what I want is a matrix of structs.

So the row index is time and column index is a MultiIndex. Any opinions of doing it this way?

Alternatively, I am thinking of using panels, where first dimension is time, second dimension is sensor, and third dimension is attribute. The thing about panel is that it appears less used and maybe there are fewer tools to work with it.

Comment: What operations do you want to perform? Your multi-index solution seems perfectly fine. Panel currently lacks some functionality and has less helpful documentation, so I would say doing the multi-index DataFrame is better. But it depends on what you need to do with the data. If you only need to do simple things, a `dict` of `dicts` could be easy enough, then just write a few functions for making it easier to pull out the data you want.

Comment: The data is huge and dict of dict will run out of memory.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Pandas DataFrame is not much more than a `dict` of `dict` already, with one level of keys for columns and then another level that is essentially just a mapping to the index of the underlying arrays. Of course you would not have a separate `dict` for each row (that's not what I meant). So if `dict` of `dict` would run out of memory, DataFrame probably would too. (Now, the behavior could be quite different for *operations* on the data, but you haven't given specifics about that either).

Comment: if its too big for memory, you can still use this structure and chunk to/from a ``HDFStore``, docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#hdf5-pytables)